# django subracting datetime fields

Tags: python, django

I am using an model which has fields named start_time and finish_time, both are DateTimeField, I'm trying to calculate the response time by subtracting finish_time with start_time.

In shell:

```
>>> obj = Quizgame.objects.get(user=harry)
>>> start = obj.start_time
>>> end = obj.finish_time
>>> result = end - start
>>> result
datetime.timedelta(seconds=31, microseconds=912224)
```

But In django Views, when I perform this I'll get an error of **unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'datetime.datetime'**

```
views.py

def final_part(request):
    obj = Quizgame.objects.get(user=request.user)
    start = obj.start_time
    end = obj.end_time
    result = end - start
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

```
models.py
class Quizgame(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_score = models.DecimalField("Total score", default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    finish_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I later set the finish time using datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: one uses `finish_time` and the other uses `end_time`.

Comment: put your Quizegame model code too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used obj.end_time instead of obj.finish_time

```
def final_part(request):
    obj = Quizgame.objects.get(user=request.user)
    start = obj.start_time
    end = obj.finish_time
    result = end - start
    return HttpResponse(result)
```